# Is there a port variable which can be used for nginx upstream servers?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I am using upstream server definitions for load balancing. In there I can define a list of servers like followed:

```
upstream backend {
    server 192.168.1.1:1234;
    server 192.168.1.2:1234;
    server 192.168.1.3:1234;
}
```

But in this case `backend` would only forward to port `1234`.

What I'd need is a generic definition similar to this:

```
upstream backend {
    server 192.168.1.1:$port;
    server 192.168.1.2:$port;
    server 192.168.1.3:$port;
}
```

That way I wouldn't need to define an upstream block for each port, thus I won't need to adapt upstream server definitions for each new service.